# How to get cluster id using WMI on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: python, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

There is cluster ID property that can be retrieved with `Get-Cluster | select Id` in powershell command.

How to get it with WMI? Looks like MSCluster_Cluster doesn't have ID field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to find cluster id on my own. Just in case if anyone looking for same.

Found the cluster id in registry.
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Cluster`

Key: `ClusterInstanceId`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this through WMI using ROOT\MSCluster:MSCluster_ClusterService.ElementName. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/cluswmiext/mscluster-clusterservice